# I'm wanting to combine unknown number of rows into one

Tags: sql-server-2012

Here is an example of data:

**TABLE: DRIVERS**

```
ID    | FNAME | LNAME
------+-------+------
WR558 | WILL  | RIKER
WW123 | WALT  | WHITE
```

**TABLE: ACCIDENTS**

```
DRIVER | ACCIDENT_NBR | ACCI_DATE  | ACCI_CITY | ACCI_ST
-------+--------------+------------+-----------+--------
WW123  | 4-7777       | 2014-01-01 | Chicago   | IL
WW123  | 4-7782       | 2014-01-03 | Houston   | TX
WW123  | 4-7988       | 2014-01-15 | El Paso   | NM
```

There could be any number of accidents listed for this driver in this table or there could be none

**What i need to see is this:**

```
ID    | FNAME | LNAME  | ACCIDENT1_NBR | ACCI1_DATE | ACCI1_CITY | ACCI1_ST | ACCIDENT2_NBR | ACCI2_DATE | ACCI2_CITY | ACCI2_ST | ACCIDENT3_NBR | ACCI3_DATE | ACCI3_CITY | ACCI3_ST | ... | ACCIDENT10_NBR | ACCI10_DATE | ACCI10_CITY | ACCI10_ST
------+-------+--------+---------------+------------+------------+----------+---------------+
WR558 | WILL  |  RIKER |               |            |            |          |               | ...
WW123 | WALT  |  WHITE | 4-7777        | 2014-01-01 | Chicago    | IL       | 4-7782        | ...
```

I need to pull the driver info and the 10 most recent accidents (if any) onto this one line.  I'm unsure if I need to use a PIVOT table or a FETCH.  Either way, I'm not sure how to iterate into the columns as needed.

Anyone's assistance is greatly appreciated!

*I'm using SQL Server 2012 and this will ultimately get pulled into a .XLS SSRS file.  The pipes I included are only for display and will not be part of the final result*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use PIVOT for this as ugly as it will be it is the correct choice if coding a C# solution is not viable.

Here is an example:  [Simple Pivot sample](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12169016/simple-pivot-sample)