# sql query join with condition on joined table

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

I have these following tables:

**`suppliers`**

```
id | name
-----------
1  | sample
```

**`addresses`**

```
id | address | owner_type | owner_id
-------------------------------------
1  | adres   | Supplier   | 1
```

**`phone_numbers`**

```
id | number | owner_type | owner_id | phone_type
------------------------------------------------
1  | 12345  | Supplier   | 1        | phone
2  | 67890  | Supplier   | 1        | fax
```

It seem not a problem for me for addresses table, I use this query, I tested it and it work fine.

```
Select suppliers.*, addresses.address AS address FROM suppliers LEFT JOIN addresses ON (addresses.owner_id = suppliers.id AND addresses.owner_type = 'Supplier')
```

Now the problem is in `phone_number` table, there is 2 record with 2 different conditional, as you can see:

```
id | number | owner_type | owner_id | phone_type
------------------------------------------------
1  | 12345  | Supplier   | 1        | phone
2  | 67890  | Supplier   | 1        | fax
```

There is `phone_type` field -> `phone` and `fax`, and I want to show both of that in result, like this:

```
id  | name   | address | phone | fax
---------------------------------
1   | sample | adres   | 12345 | 67890
```

I try this query:

```
LEFT JOIN phone_numbers ON (phone_numbers.owner_id = suppliers.id AND phone_numbers.owner_type = 'Supplier' AND phone_type = 'phone')
```

Unfortunately that query just for 1 condition (`phone`) , how I get the fax value?

I use PostgreSQL.

Comment: Do a second left join on the phone_numbers table but this time use the phone_type of 'fax'.

Comment: Let try the below link this may help you,
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12169016/simple-pivot-sample

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can join the phone_numbers tables two times using different alias.One for phone and one for fax. Like below P1 for phone and P2 for fax.

```
Select suppliers.*, addresses.address AS address ,P1.number as 'Phone', P2.number as 'Fax'
FROM suppliers 
LEFT JOIN addresses ON (addresses.owner_id = suppliers.id AND addresses.owner_type = 'Supplier')
LEFT JOIN phone_numbers P1 ON (P1.owner_id = suppliers.id AND P1.owner_type = 'Supplier' AND P1.phone_type = 'phone')
LEFT JOIN phone_numbers P2 ON (P2.owner_id = suppliers.id AND P2.owner_type = 'Supplier' AND P2.phone_type = 'fax')
```

Comment: wow,, its fantastic, its work very fine, thank you so much bro,,,,

Comment: For more complex situations where number of types (such as phone_type) are more or variable (not fixed), you can explore pivot functionality for converting rows values to columns values.